# angularfire signedIn function only evaluates when page refreshes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am hiding html login and register links when a user is logged in with firebase and angular. 
With the use of  **ng-show**  and **ng-hide** by evaluating signedIn() function in my Auth.js factory.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ng-show="signedIn()"><a href="#/create">Create a Post</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li ng-hide="signedIn()"><a href="#/register">Register</a></li>
    <li ng-hide="signedIn()"><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
    <li ng-show="signedIn()" class="dropdown">
      <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
         {{currentUser.profile.name}}
         <i class="mdi mdi-account"></i>
         <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
```

Here is my Auth factory service:

```
angular.module('AuthService',[])
  .factory('Auth', function($firebaseAuth, $firebase){

  var ref = new Firebase("https://ngblogapp.firebaseio.com/");
  var authObj = $firebaseAuth(ref);
  var authData = authObj.$getAuth(); //firebase auth data when you login 

  var Auth = {
    user:{},

    createProfile: function(uid, user){
      var profile = {
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password,
      };

      var profileRef = $firebaseObject(ref.child('profile'));
        console.log("User Register Data : " + profileRef);
        return profileRef.$set(uid, profile);
    },
    login: function(user){
      return authObj.$authWithPassword(
        {email: user.email, password: user.password}
      ).then(function(authData) {
        console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
      });
    },
    register: function(user){
      return authObj.$createUser({email: user.email, password: user.password})
      .then(function(userData) {
        console.log("User " + userData.uid + " created successfully!");
        return authObj.$authWithPassword({
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password,
        });
      }).then(function(authData) {
        console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error: ", error);
      });
    },
    logout: function(){
      authObj.$unauth(); //logout method
    },
    changePassword: function(user){
      return authObj.$changePassword({email: user.email, oldPassword: user.oldpass, newPassword: user.newpass});
    },
    signedIn: function(){
      var  signedin = authData === null ? false : true; //check to see if you are logged in
      console.log("signed in status is " + signedin);
      return signedin;
    }
  }; // end Auth
  if (authData) {
    console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
  } else {
    console.log("Logged out");
  }
  return Auth;
});
```

I am returning my signedIn function with a controller. Here is the controller:

```
app.controller('AuthController', function($scope, $location, Auth){

  $scope.register = function(user){
    Auth.register(user).then(function(){
      console.log("Register successfully!");
      $location.path("/");
    }, function(err){
      console.log("Error...");
    });
  };
```

The code stated above works and hides the login and register links  **only on browser refresh** 

*What is erroneous in my code in angularfire and specifically in signedIn method to work automatically after I sign in or sign off?*

Comment: Can you put this into a Plnkr or a JSBin? It would make it much easier to work through.

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed the problem. My factory has a register , login, and logout method which were fully functioning, however firebase's getAuth only evaluates once. To hack fix the issue I had to reload the page, but the proper fix for the issue, I had to place `document.reload();`
at the end of register,login, and logout functions.

Here is a preview of that.

```
login: function(user){
      return authObj.$authWithPassword(
        {email: user.email, password: user.password}
      ).then(function(authData) {
        console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
        return authData; 
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
      }, location.reload()); //reload page after login
    },
    logout: function(){
      authObj.$unauth(); 
      location.reload(); //reload page
    },
```

The  **location.reload()**  method will reload the document after a logout or login and firebase getAuth() will evaluate properly, therefore allowing me to use ng-hide or ng-show for hiding and showing my html templates on my navbar to show log state.

Now when logged off the navbar will show a register and login link

[image]

And when logged in or registered in you will see logout options in the navbar.

[image]